# Custom view is not clickable after addSubview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

View hierarchy before `addSubview`:

View > TableView

View hierarchy after `addSubview`:

View > TableView && View > CustomView

After calling `addSubview`, CustomView is shown on top of TableView as its frame is smaller and it was added after TableView. However, I have buttons and textfields in the CustomView, none of which are working. Even when I tap on the CustomView the TableView's scrollView seems to be capturing the tapGesture. How can I make it so that the CustomView's buttons and textfields to accept touches?

Also, background color of the CustomView is clear, showing the tableView underneath when the customView is added to the view hierarchy. I tried setting background color in the storyboard and programmatically, but it's still stuck at clear. How can I fix this?

```
class masterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

//blah blah
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! // tableView is added in the storyboard

let newForm = NewFormView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
    newForm.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(newForm)
    newForm.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        newForm.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        newForm.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
}
```

`newForm` is a `UIView` nib with buttons and textFields added in the nib storyboard

Comment: show how you add it , also does the vc a UITableViewController ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan code added, no the vc is a UIViewController with UITableView added in storyboard

Comment: As per the info you gave, go to  `Main.storyboard` and select that `CustomView` and go to `Attributes Inspector` and click tick on `user interaction enabled` checkbox. If it is already ticked, then check [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-bring-a-subview-to-the-front-of-a-uiview) post. It explain how to bring a view to the top of stack.

Comment: @Mihir just tried it, didn't work. I know for a fact that ```CustomView`` is at the top because 1. if ```CustomView``` were not at the top I would not be able to see the Buttons and Labels, as they would be hidden by ```tableView``` and 2. I used View Hierarchy Debugging in Xcode to make sure that the entire ```CustomView``` is on top of the view hierarchy after ```addSubview```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add width and height constraints

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    newForm.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    newForm.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
    newForm.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:300),
    newForm.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:300)
])
```

As when you do

```
newForm.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

your frame becomes invalid and not active in receiving touches

Comment: I'm an idiot haha rip past 1 hour of my life, thanks a lot!